# How can I switch using pip between system and anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am now using anaconda pip after I installed pip by "conda install pip", if I want to use system pip again, how can I make it? Or how can I switch system pip to anaconda pip?

Answer (score 6):

Odds are that anaconda automatically edited your `.bashrc` so that anaconda/bin is in front of your `/usr/bin` folder in your `$PATH` variable.  To check this, type `echo $PATH`, and the command line will return a list of directory paths.  Your computer checks each of these places for pip when you type pip in the command line.  It executes the first one it finds in your `PATH`.

You can open `/home/username/.bashrc` with whatever text editor you choose.  Wherever it adds anaconda/bin to the path, with something like `export PATH=/anaconda/bin:$PATH` , just replace it with `export PATH=$PATH:/anaconda/bin`

Note though, this will change your OS to use your system python as well.  Instead of all of this, you can always just use the direct path to pip when calling it.  Or you can alias it using `alias pip=/path/to/system/pip`.  And you can put that line in your .bashrc file in order to apply it whenever you login to the pc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change your path. Just use the full path to the system pip (generally `/usr/bin/pip` or `/usr/local/bin/pip`) to use the system pip.

Comment: I should use "/usr/bin/pip install package" if I wan to use system pip; otherwise, I may use "/anaconda/bin/pip install package", is it correct?